# Svelte #each over array of constants how?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Making first steps with Svelte and already loving it , noob question but I guess Svelte can not track such an update?

What would be Svelte way of writing this?

Uncommenting 2 would work, but even though I see different values in

when I click Weeks , Weeks in #each do not receive "new" selected updates

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { getDays } from '$lib/calendar';
    import Week from './Week.svelte';

    let days = getDays(new Date());

    let selected = 2;

    function handleSelect(week_n) {
        // console.log(week_n);
        selected = week_n;
    }
</script>

<p>Select {selected}</p>

<div class="isolate mt-2 grid grid-rows-5 gap-px rounded-lg  text-sm shadow ring-1 ring-gray-200">
    {#each [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] as week_n, i}
        <Week
            week={week_n === selected // 2
                ? days.slice(week_n * 7, week_n * 7 + 7).map((d) => ({ ...d, selected: true }))
                : days.slice(week_n * 7, week_n * 7 + 7)}
            on:select={(ev) => handleSelect(week_n)}
        />
    {/each}
</div>
```

and the Week component

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    import WeekDay from './WeekDay.svelte';

    export let week;

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    function select() {
        dispatch('select', {
            text: 'Hello!'
        });
    }
</script>

<button
    type="button"
    class="rounded-tl-lg py-1.5 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:z-10"
    on:click={select}
>
    <div class="mx-auto flex">
        {#each week as { datetime, dd, isToday, thisMonth, selected }, i}
            <WeekDay {datetime} {dd} {isToday} {thisMonth} {selected} />
        {/each}
    </div>
</button>
```

including leaf WeekDay also for completeness

```js
<script lang="ts">
    export let datetime;
    export let dd;
    export let isToday;
    export let thisMonth;
    export let selected; // = false;

    export let topLeft;
    export let topRight;
    export let bottomLeft;
    export let bottomRight;

    let timeClass = 'mx-auto flex h-7 w-7 items-center justify-center rounded-full';

    if (selected || isToday) {
        timeClass += ' font-semibold';
    }

    if (!selected && !isToday && thisMonth) timeClass += ' bg-white text-gray-900';

    if (!selected && !isToday && !thisMonth) timeClass += ' bg-gray-50';

    if (isToday && !selected) timeClass += ' text-indigo-600';

    if (selected && isToday) timeClass += ' bg-indigo-600 text-white';

    if (selected && !isToday) timeClass += ' bg-gray-900 text-white';
</script>

<time {datetime} class={timeClass}>{dd}</time>
```

Comment: Uncommenting 2 would work, but even though I see different values in <p> when I click Weeks , Weeks in #each do not receive "new" selected updates

Comment: Please just edit the question instead of commenting on it.

Comment: Also, include the code of the `Week` component, the issue might be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not reactive the whole way, the properties get changed but the changes don't propagate.

The `let timeClass` in `WeekDay` and all the subsequent `if` statements only happen once.

To fix that, it should be `$: timeClass = ...` and `$: if (...) ...`, but that could be done more functionally. Something like:

```js
$: classes = [
  ['mx-auto flex h-7 w-7 items-center justify-center rounded-full', true],
  ['font-semibold', selected || isToday],
  ...
]
.filter(x => x[1]).map(x => x[0])
.join(' ')
```

Also, the `week` property should not require a ternary:

```html
week={days.slice(week_n * 7, week_n * 7 + 7)
  .map(d => ({ ...d, selected: week_n === selected }))}
```

Comment: Such a nice functional hint! Thanks you @H.B.